# Summing up loop values

Tags: sql, plsql

I am working on a pl/sql procedure where I am using loop to pass values. Loop is working as expected however, I have specific ask regarding the value which I am storing in the loop. So if my loop is running 5 times and by using counter I am able to see that loop is running 5 times but let's suppose internal loop query is running 5 times but it will only satisfy the query 3 times and I want to take sum of that. please find the below query.

```
begin
   SELECT COUNT(Stop_type) into v_pkp_cnt from shipment_stop where shipment_gid = '00500455';

   for c in (SELECT (STOP_num) into v_cnt from shipment_stop where shipment_gid = '00500455')

   loop

   select count (distinct (ies.shipment_gid)) into v_stp_cnt from  ie_shipmentstatus ies , shipment_stop 
   ss
   where 
   ies.shipment_gid = ss.shipment_gid
   and ss.stop_num = c.stop_num 
   and ies.shipment_gid = '00500455'
   and ies.status_code_gid = '24-1'
   and ies.attribute3 = ss.location_gid;
   l_cnt := l_cnt+1; 

   end loop;

   end;
```

here v_stp_cnt is giving me 1 for 4 times but instead of 1 for 4 times I want to sum up v_stp_cnt values and I want 4 as a result. How can I sum up?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Yes, I re-read it 3 times. FOR loop statement is invalid, that's for sure. Should have probably been `for i in 1 .. v_cnt loop`, where `v_cnt` gets it value using that `select stop_num into v_cnt` statement. But, what to do then? I really don't understand ...

Comment: Loop is working fine for now.  My main concern is to sum up the values for v_stp_cnt. V_stp_cnt could be 0 or 1 always. And let's say if my loop runs four times and then v_stp_cnt will have the result as like  v_stp_cnt = 1 , v_stp_cnt = 1, v_stp_cnt = 0, v_stp_cnt =1 but I want to sum up these and show it as 1+1+0+1 = 3.

Comment: You say you want to sum up `v_stp_cnt` but the code doesn't populate it, and instead increments `l_cnt`, although neither of them is declared anyway. `for` loops don't have an `into` clause and so the compiler is ignoring `into v_cnt`, though you don't seem to do anything with that either.

Comment: You get the wrong result in l_cnt ( I think that is the variable you want, but not completely sure) because you **are not summing** the values you are counting them. And while 0 dos not increase the summation it is still a value that is counted.  So you need something like l_stp_sum := l_stp_sum + v_stp_cnt (?), but since you selected count(...) I not sure, Either way you should get rid of that calculation and the loop entirely by select sum(ies.shipment_gid) into ...